# Total Interest not taking part of the equation

Tags: java

I don't know whats the problem with my program when I try to run it with *.getMonthlyDue* the process to solve is Total Loan/Payment Term only, the TotalInterest isn't included in the equation

```
public class Loan {


    public String Name;
    public int Age;
    public double TotalLoan;
    public int PaymentTerm;
    private double Interest;
    private double TotalInterest;
    private double MonthlyDue;

    public Loan() //default constructor
    {
        Name = "";
        Age = 0;
        TotalLoan = 0;
        PaymentTerm = 0;
    }

    public Loan(String Nam, int Ag, double Total, int Term) //with parameters
    {
        Name = Nam;
        Age = Ag;
        TotalLoan = Total;
        PaymentTerm = Term;
    }

    //implementors
    public void setName(String Nam) {
        Name = Nam;
    }
    public void setAge(int Ag) {
        Age = Ag;
    }
    public void setTotalLoan(double Total) {
        TotalLoan = Total;
    }
    public void setPaymentTerm(int Term) {
        PaymentTerm = Term;
    }

    //access
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    public double getTotalLoan() {
        return TotalLoan;
    }
    public int getPaymentTerm() {
        return PaymentTerm;
    }
    public double getInterest() {
        calcInterest();
        return Interest;
    }
    public double getTotalInterest() {
        calcTotalInterest();
        return TotalInterest;
    }
    public double getMonthlyDue() {
        calcMonthlyDue();
        return MonthlyDue;
    }

    //facilitators
    private void calcInterest() {
        if (TotalLoan < 100001) {
            Interest = 0.10;
        } else if (TotalLoan > 100001 & TotalLoan <= 250000) {
            Interest = 0.15;
        } else if (TotalLoan > 250001 & TotalLoan <= 500000) {
            Interest = 0.20;
        } else {
            Interest = 0.25;
        }
    }

    private void calcTotalInterest() {
        TotalInterest = TotalLoan + Interest;
    }
    private void calcMonthlyDue() {
        MonthlyDue = (TotalLoan + TotalInterest) / PaymentTerm;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged your code? also: read up on naming conventions and default values, it'll make your code compacter and easier to read.

Comment: I already debugged it. thank you for the tip .

Comment: you don't change anything about TotalInterest, so why would it be anything but 0? if that is your question

Comment: uh im sorry i cant express it better. but im trying to solve monthlydue in this problem. when i set like 100k total loan and 12 months of term it solves 8333.33333 instead of 9166.67

Comment: The `totalInterest` is only initialized when you call `getInterest()` and `getTotalInterest()` first. Do you call these methods?

Comment: so i need to do the equation at the main too? sorry im really not getting it.

Comment: @crisonix you are coding a method that will perform the calculation, but you are not executing that method

Comment: so how do i execute the method?

Comment: by calling it, just like you execute any other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider refactoring your code such that the bean class (data structure) has no logic of its own. Remove the calculation methods ("facilitators") and put them somewhere else (another java class) with public methods.

```
public double calcInterest(double totalLoan) {
    if (totalLoan < 100001) {
        return 0.10;
    }
    if (totalLoan > 100001 & totalLoan <= 250000) {
        return 0.15;
    }
    if (totalLoan > 250001 & totalLoan <= 500000) {
        return 0.20;
    }
    return 0.25;
}

public double calcTotalInterest(double totalLoan, double interest) {
    // your original calculation is TotalInterest = TotalLoan + Interest;
    // if you want to know the total interest on the loan (what is owed on top of the loan itself) it should be written as below, where interest is your interest rate returned from the previous method.
    return totalLoan * interest;
}

public double calcMonthlyDue(double totalLoan, double totalInterest, int paymentTerm) {
    return (totalLoan + totalInterest) / (double) paymentTerm;
}
```

You can then call these methods as appropriate, providing the arguments as needed.

As suggested in the comments, have a look at Java naming conventions [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Also, it's better to avoid literals (like in the interest method). For someone else reading the code later it's not really clear what they mean and they're not reusable. The better alternative would be to define some constants.

Comment: I got it . Thanks for the help and also for the tips you guys gave :)